# Access Is Denied in IE only

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, iframe, permission-denied

This is not a dupe of [permission-denied-ie-iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953158/permission-denied-ie-iframe) but it is very closely related.

I have a page hosted at http://www.enviroissues.com/comments/bpa_i5/default.aspx. This page is being displayed in an IFrame  at http://www.bpa.gov/corporate/i-5-eis/ecomment.cfm.

I am NOT trying to access dom elements on one domain from the other. My page should be working fine independently of where it is being displayed and it is working fine in IE when I go to it's direct url.

When viewing through the IFrame however, I'm getting the error 'Access is Denied jquery-1.3-min.js Line 19, etc etc...

I can only assume that there may be some conflicting IDs on both pages of an element I'm trying to manipulate, but I haven't found one.

Does anybody else have any ideas on what to look for?

Comment: jQuery 1.3 (even 1.3.2) predates IE8.  If you're supporting IE8 (and you really should be), you need to update to 1.4.x (1.4.2 is the newest version as of this writing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is caused by a bug in the version of jQuery you're running.

http://www.webgyver.com/web-design-and-development/jquery-13-not-ready-for-production/

Try updating to the latest version.

Your code is blowing up on this statement in jQuery:

```
if(document.documentElement.doScroll&&!l.frameElement)
```

Comment: +1: I've had similar problems to this with jQuery 1.3.2 having problems with certain things in IE8 that upgrading to 1.4.2 fixed.  jQuery 1.3 predates IE8 by several months, and unsurprisingly has things that don't work properly in it.